# How to retrieve data from Postgresql index using C#

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql, postgresql-9.4

I have created an index called `table_index` from the table `table_name` in PostgreSQL using the following:

```
CREATE INDEX table_index
ON table_name (column1_name, column2_name);
```

Now how can I access the `colum1_name` and `column2_name` values from C# code.

Comment: What did you even try? Npgsql has pretty decent documentation: http://www.npgsql.org/doc/index.html

Comment: The documents contains for accessing the table. and its not saying anything about table_index.

Comment: It is the documentation for the library you have chosen to use - did you even go through it all? Also, you have yet to even show your attempt at a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot retrieve data from an index. You retrieve data from tables. Indexes are data structures that aid the database engine in finding data you request in the table. It is the database engines choice to use the index or not.

For instance if you do the query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column1_name=$1
```

then the database engine may decide to use your index to find the data you requested.